# How to integrate Google Assistant with a custom bluetooth-only device?

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, actions-on-google, google-home

I want to develop my own bluetooth device similar to "C by GE" light bulbs which use bluetooth protocol and don't require any hub.

How does Assistant's discovery and fulfillment work in this case? Since there's no wi-fi in the device, there is no webhook to call. Is there any documentation or examples of using this technology?

Comment: To use assistant, you will need Internet connectivity as assistant / dialogflow is Software as a Service.  In your story, is there to be no internet connectivity?  If yes, please supply a high level component diagram.

Comment: GE light bulbs work by using Google Home devices as their internet bridges. They don't need their own bridge and Google Home/Assistant infrastructure seamlessly integrates with them. But since the device itself doesn't have internet connectivity, it's up to Assistant to communicate with it through Google Home device.